# Adjust navbar based on the number of menus inside

Tags: php, jquery, css, cakephp

Very new to CakePHP, trying to make a navbar that adjust itself based on the number of menu it has.

To elaborate here's an image:
[image]
The navbar changes dynamically based on the person who is logged in. For example, When person A logs in the navbar has 6 menus, when person B logs in it has 4 menus, same for person C when he logs in.

How can I do this? Not familiar with the term that's why my research could have been inadequate, but so far a friend told me that it could be done with CSS and jQuery.

Comment: It certainly can be some with CSS. Can you post the code for your current navbar and what you've tried already to make it auto-size the menu items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do this is using `display: table` and `width: 100%` for the menu, and `display: table-cell` for the menu items. This will make the items be displayed horizontally.

Then you should use javascript (or in you case, jQuery) to set the items width.

I made a fiddle where I show a simple solution: http://jsfiddle.net/8Qh8h/